# How to use ApplyToEach when operation has parameters?

Tags: q#

**Problem**

Apply a global phase -1 to all qubits `x : Qubit[]`.

**My solution**

`ApplyToEach(R, PauliI, 2.0 * PI(), x)`

However this yields a syntax error.

From the [ApplyToEach doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.canon.applytoeach), it works if the operation has no parameters:

```
using (register = Qubit[3]) {
    ApplyToEach(H, register);
}
```

Thank you for your expertise. Happy qubitting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [partial application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/language/expressions#partial-application) to specify the rest of the parameters passed to the R gate. The result of partial application will be a gate that takes a single qubit as an argument, and `ApplyToEach` will be able to apply it to each element of the array:

```
using (register = Qubit[3]) {
    let globalPhaseGate = R(PauliI, 2.0 * PI(), _);
    ApplyToEach(globalPhaseGate, qs);
}
```

You can also write this shorter, without using an extra constant to name the gate that is the result of partial application:

```
using (register = Qubit[3]) {
    ApplyToEach(R(PauliI, 2.0 * PI(), _), register);
}
```

Comment: Nice! I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.